# Missing files after zsh mv: command error. Are they deleted? Or where?

Tags: linux, scripting, zsh

I am using the following script to turn a folder of 100000 .jpg photos into 10 folders of 10000 .jpg photos.

`i=0; for f in *; do d=dir_$(printf %03d $((i/10000+1))); mkdir -p $d; mv "$f" $d; let i++; done`

It works great besides one problem:

Filenames that have Spanish characters in them, such as Jalapeños.jpg, cause this to be thrown:

`mv: rename Jalapeños.jpg to dir_001/Jalapeños.jpg: No such file or directory.`

Every single file that this has happened to is now completely missing. Can anyone confirm what happened here or know where my files are? Are they deleted somehow?

Comment: I have been unable to reproduce this on my systems.  Try isolating the issue, and see if it occurs outside the for loop. Also, see what file system you're using (one way to do that is the `mount` command with no parameters), and look on the web for how to deal with that particular fs.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] so we can test.